# How to get Eclipse + PyDev + App Engine + Unit testing to work?

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine, pydev

I want to run my unit tests for a Python Google App Engine project using

> Run As => Python unit-test

But when I try that all my Model tests bail with the error message:

```
BadArgumentError: app must not be empty.
```

Anyone got this to work?

*NB: The tests runs fine using Nose --with-gae. But I want the PyDev integration with hyperlinking of resources and such.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pasting the answer I got from the Fabioz (the PyDev creator) himself over at the PyDev forums on SF: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pydev/forums/forum/293649/topic/3618848

> There's no such option right now... please enter a feature request for that. Note that you can run nose itself from inside of pydev (with the --with-gae option) -- which at least would give you hyperlinking inside of pydev -- to do that just create a custom run where nose is the main script.

Indeed, that's what I did and it works as advertised. I also entered that feature request. You can help by pushing your support behind the request: https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2974043&group_id=85796&atid=577332

Comment: Just stumbled on this. Thank you @PEZ. Any progress on your feature request in last 3 years? Also, can you please elaborate on the nose? Is that the only option? What '--with-gae' does, and can I do it manually?

Comment: As a note, right now both nose and pytest are supported unittest runners, you just need to configure it inside PyDev (see: http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_pyunit.html for details).